# Checking localhost (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to determine if an application is currently running on localhost. On the web, I can use window.location to define localhost in the url string. I am using Androud Studio to emulate android devices + expo. How do I tell if I'm in development mode in React Native?

Comment: did you mean debug app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global variable `__DEV__`

The definition from the documentation is:

*This variable is set to true when react-native is running in Dev mode*

Example:

```
const myEnv = __DEV__ ? 'DEV' : 'PROD';

.....
<Text>{myEnv}</Text>
```